# Is it possible to assign a partial wildcard to a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I search for a while to see if it is possible, i could not find anything, but maybe what i want is possible and i just searched with the wrong search terms.

What i want to do

```
type a = 'String' | 'String/' + string;
const b: a = 'String/anything';
```

Comment: Such a type is impossible in typescript unfortunately because there is no way to join string literal types together

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works as of Typescript v4.1 with the introduction of template literals:

```
type a = "String" | `String/${string}`
const b: a = "String" // Valid
const c: a = "String123" // Invalid
const d: a = "String/123" // Valid
const e: a = "String/" // Valid
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5&ssl=5&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UBEBlYAnAlgOwOZKgB8oADNLPAegBIBvAZwx1wF8SAoAYwHttGoARgC5YCZOWYFKlKADUYAG0wATLr36cRcRKiZ4AjACYAzFJkBJbADdFKtX2BRlWsboq5KR01GlzbqngcoCBcdCSozPyVVIA)

Answer (score 3):

TS4.1+

Pattern template literals, as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) and introduced with TS4.1, now allow this:

```
type a = 'String' | `String/${string}`;
const b: a = 'String/anything';
```

See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71505621/2887218) also.

---

TS4.0-

TypeScript does not have this feature (as of v3.5, anyway).  There is an existing [suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) to allow using regular expressions to pick out subtypes of `string`.  If that were implemented, you would be able to do something like:

```
// THE FOLLOWING CODE IS NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT, DO NOT USE
type a = /^String(\/.*)?$/;
const b: a = "String/anything"; // okay
```

If you really want to see this happen you might want to go over to that issue in GitHub and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's there already.

---

The closest workaround you could use today would be something without any compile-time validation.  You could make a [branded primitive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) to stand for your `a` type, and a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to perform validation at runtime instead of compile time:

```
type a = string & { __brand: "type a" };
function isA(x: string): x is a {
  return /^String(\/.*)?$/.test(x);
}
```

Then you could define `b` like:

```
const b = "String/anything";
if (!isA(b)) throw new Error(b + "does not match type a");
```

and, after that code, `b` is known to be of type `a` by the compiler:

```
function acceptOnlyA(a: a) {}
acceptOnlyA(b); // okay
```

So that works as far as it goes.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBUAkFFQMQPIBkkIOoEkByBxUBhBAEVgwGVQsFxQA1AQSQyIgE0AFaM-AJQ3fAAaUEQSVqoAKploAWABQIUABcAngAcApqACGoALyhgAPTLKATgEsAdgHMAFAB1gAOgBUASgD8AEmABuBSUAYwB7awBnZVAAIwAuXQNQACIzKztgHWtVZQALG1tk-yMwUIBrHVUFBTUtRMMo9NtQADJQAG9QAH0umPMsgBME5NrtHWTQAF9A+QAzAFdrYOVLcNBLCPp7AA8ExoKPBO31iMT2hVBQc01lefNrI1MLAqdXT19XZU0onY8ZyYUYUi0RiSVSzwyWRy+TsRQUllmoHsAEINlsYh4PCpcuZQgB3UDWTQE6DmXHmeyggDUKQGoW+hNC0QAtjplMFcioNGNkn9qnNFstVg8dMFgpp1MoENYADaqLY6BI6LHtAHyUXiyXSuXov4lUDlSoKIA)